# How can I create a NETSTANDARD2.0 project on OSX?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I am definitely prefering a minimal tooling solution using `VSCODE/IONIDE` or `FORGE`.

Comment: Not sure about VSCode, but you can try Rider: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/12/21/project-templates-rider-2017-3/ - it looks like it has template for netstandard2.0

Answer (score 1):

How about `dotnet new classlib -lang F# -n your_lib`? .Net standard 2.0 is default. I'm not sure whether you can do that in VSCode GUI, but you sure can use integrated terminal.